# What is best practice for validating an object before passing it to an ORM helper class to persist it

Tags: java, orm

Say you have an instance of your DB entity class MyClass.
You have 3 fields in this entity which are all tagged as "Cannot be null"
If you create an object of this class and pass it along to be persisted you DB layer will throw an exception when it tries to persist the object if it does NOT have the 3 fields populated.
What is the best practice in this situation.
Should the constructor, setter methods in MyClass validate that all fields are correct and if not complain.
Or do you allow an invalid object to be created and have the DB layer do the complaining?

Comment: Check [Hibernate validator framework](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)  You should prevent the client from submitting an invalid data

2)  Even if you do 1, you still need to validate on the server -- people will try wacky things with curl and wget...

3)  I would check in the service layer that the incoming data is valid.  If it is not, I would return some sort of error code to the client, and not even do the save.  For simple cases I would have a `validate` method on my domain class.  For complicated cases, I would create a service method to do the validation, for example, in the case where I need to check the submitted data against data in the DB. There is no 1 right way to do validation that covers all cases.

The problem with doing the save and catching the exception is it can be difficult to distinguish this error from other errors that can occur.  Plus, it's easy to test validation code, and that the service does the right thing on validation failure.  Plus, validation logic is business rules, and it's always good to be able to easily test your business rules.

Comment: Yes, you ought to know that it's good well in advance of the persistence tier.  The service needs to protect itself; it should not trust clients.

Comment: Validation should be done in the presentation layer (or at least, everything that is possible to validate there). That's where it costs the less, and where appropriate error messages can be generated and displayed. If the presentation layer is not completely under your control, or if you want additional checks, validating in the service layer is also necessary.

Comment: JB yes that is my #1.  Personally, I would validate on the server as well, all the time, even if there is 1 client and I control it.

Comment: I agree with hvgotcodes, because a service layer should not trust that the client has done validation.  Even if it does, there are different levels of validation.  The client can check for required elements and formats, but it can't know about business rules. That's best left for the service layer.

Comment: My point was that, in a web app, validation in JavaScript is an added bonus, but is hard to implement, and easy to circumvent. Validation in the presentation layer of the server code is where it should be done. And if some clients are not under your control, or if you want belts and suspenders, then the service layer should also validate. I hate to put validation methods into domain objects, though, because IMHO, validation depends on the use-case and not on the object. If you have a multi-step wizard, or if you can create and modify the same object, the same rules don't apply.

Comment: Seems this is a clear cut answer.  Validate as soon as possible. Thnx

Comment: @duffymo: agreed with the business rules validation. That's what I meant with "additional checks".

Comment: I think we're on the same page, JBN.

Comment: the only difference I can see from this opinion and my answer is where the validation occurs on the server.  JB appears to do like to validate outside the service code....

Comment: Yes indeed, that's why I upvoted for this answer. Just wanted to add my two cents.